# How to define relationship between xmls in MarkLogic and use it while search API?

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8, marklogic-7

These are the documents I have inserted in the database.

```
<biblio>
    <biblioid>123</biblioid>
    <mediaid>456</mediaid>
    <name>dixit</name>
    <title>title</title>
</biblio>

<biblio>
    <biblioid>456</biblioid>
    <mediaid>789</mediaid>
    <name>singla</name>
    <title>title1</title>
</biblio>

<media>
    <mediaid>456</mediaid>
    <mediaName>media1</mediaName>
    <title>hello</title>
</media>

<media>
    <mediaid>789</mediaid>
    <mediaName>media1</mediaName>
    <title>hello</title>
</media>

<media>
    <mediaid>384</mediaid>
    <mediaName>media2</mediaName>
    <title>hello</title>
</media>
```

I want to search those documents having `<name>` in `<biblio>` as **"Dixit"** and `<medianame>` in `<media>` as **"media1"**.

But it should check  of only those documents having `<mediaid>` is same as in `biblio/mediaid`

As in our case, the result will be

```
<biblio>
    <biblioid>123</biblioid>
    <mediaid>456</mediaid>
    <name>dixit</name> <!-- name is matching ("dixit")-->
    <title>title</title>
</biblio>

<media>
    <mediaid>456</mediaid> <!-- mediaid is same as in biblio/mediaid  -->
    <mediaName>media1</mediaName> <!-- medianame is matching ("media1") -->
    <title>hello</title>
</media>
```

I can achieve this, first by getting all the biblio docs matching the name ("dixit") then from the results I will extract the mediaid's(456) and then will query the media documents with fetched mediaid's(456) and medianame(media1).

But I want to achieve this by search:search API.

Is there any way to make this happen and Is there any place where I can define the relationship between elements of xmls.

Comment: I don't think you can do this with just one `search:seach` call. Why would you want to mingle docs and media in one query? I can only imagine you might want this for export purposes..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you put a range index on the media:id, then you will be able to do some super-fast joins. That is 1/2 the battle.

The other half is: If I wanted to do this problematically, I would do it via cts and xQuery.

BUT: If I did want to do this as part of search:search, I would do it with custom constraints - then naturally call them via the search:search library.

A possible custom constraint:
biblio-by-media-name

- search for media with the name in question
- resolve this to the biblio references
- return a ct:document-query* of the biblio docs

Then if I also had a constraint on the biblio-name called "biblio-name" then I could have a search something like the below example - all delivered via the search api in the end:

```
biblio-name:Dixit AND biblio-by-media-name:media1
```

* Note that the document-query is one approach. However, I would possibly build this not on the biblio URI, but perhaps on a range-query on the mediaid element in the biblio files. But that is all about tuning. The results will be the same in the more simplified example above.

https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/search-api#id_49750

Comment: Thanks David for your valuable answer.
Just for knowledge I would like to know how you will do it with   cts and xQuery.

Comment: you are welcome. For cts/xQuery - you will essentially use the same functions used for the custom constraint. Removing the search layer alltogether.  Does that makes sense?